# SQL Results horizontally rather than vertically

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have a `ticket_id's`,`field_id's` and values.
eg.

```
ticket_id   field_id    value
1001        1           Peter
1002        1           Dave
1001        2           555-2565
1002        2           554-2548
```

The goal is I am trying to write a query that will display values within the same table, horizontally.  eg.

```
Ticket_ID     Field1       Field2
1001          Peter        555-2565
1002          Dave         554-2548
```

There are many `field_ids`. I have tried using the `rownumber()` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: google for `mysql rank`, [this is one such](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Temp_field1.ticket_id,Field1,Field2
From
    (Select ticket_id,value as Field1 from table where field_id = 1) as Temp_field1,
    (Select ticket_id,value as Field2 from table where field_id = 2) as Temp_field2
Where Temp_field1.ticket_id = Temp_field2.ticket_id;
```

Comment: You're missing some `=` signs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TICKET_ID, MAX(FIELD_1),MAX(FIELD_2)
FROM (
    SELECT TICKET_ID, 
        CASE field_id
            WHEN 1 THEN VALUE
            ELSE NULL end AS FIELD_1,
        CASE field_id
            WHEN 2 THEN VALUE
            ELSE NULL end AS FIELD_2
)
GROUP BY FIELD_1,FIELD_2
```

It's a little quirky, but i tried to minimize the selects.
The idea is to put null when we don't need the value
and when we do MAX, it wil take the value that is not null (MAX works on VARCHAR)

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given before. You can check it here.

[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Basically you have to pivot a "group"(or a distinct) select on your field_id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. Don't know about the performance if there are many `field_ids`.

```
SELECT t1.`ticket_id` AS Ticket_ID, t1.`value` AS Field1, t2.`value` AS Field2 FROM `ticket` t1
  LEFT JOIN `ticket` t2 ON t1.`ticket_id` = t2.`ticket_id`
  WHERE t1.`value` != t2.`value`
  GROUP BY t1.`ticket_id`
```